# Randomly ordering variables

Tags: vb.net

I have 4 strings in variables a,b,c and d. I need to randomly order these variables in such a way so that I can input them into 4 different text boxes but not the same ones every time the program is ran.

I've tried to simplify it for myself by putting the strings into an array. Tell me what I'm doing wrong or if there's a way I could do it much easier.

```
    Private Sub Random()
    For i = 1 To 4
        If a = 0 Then
            a = r.Next(2, 5)
        ElseIf b = 0 Then
            Do Until b <> a
                b = r.Next(2, 5)
            Loop
        ElseIf c = 0 Then
            Do Until c <> a Or c <> b
                c = r.Next(2, 5)
            Loop
        ElseIf d = 0 Then
            Do Until d <> a Or d <> b Or d <> c
                d = r.Next(2, 5)
            Loop
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you please show us what you've tried?

Comment: There are only 4x3x2x1 = 24 possible permutations.  So just generate them up front.  Then randomly pick one and remove.  Google "vb.net permutations" for code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it:

```
Dim a As String = "a"
Dim b As String = "b"
Dim c As String = "c"
Dim d As String = "d"

Dim all As String() = {a, b, c, d}
Dim random As New Random

Dim allRandom As String() = all.OrderBy(Function() random.Next).ToArray
```